# Library Constants - How to Use

Tags: python, constants

Can someone help me on how to use the `constants` library? I am doing a sports data project and want to create a CSV file based on season dates.
I found this project on GitHub where they have used

```
from constants import SEASON_DATES
```

The following also gives an error

```
SEASON_DATES = constants.Constants()
```

but this gave me errors; so instead, I did the following:

```
import constants
SEASON_DATES = constants.Constants
```

but I am getting an error later where I invoke:

```
for season in SEASON_DATES.keys()

Error: Type object'constants' has no attribute keys
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant parts of ``constants`` to reproduce the problem. What makes you think that ``constants.Constants.keys`` is defined? Refer to the [ask] and [mcve] help pages how to best help us help you.

Comment: I think you need `consts = constants.Constants()`. Please share a working example.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the `constants` module from the [constants package](https://pypi.org/project/constants/). The example shown on that package's webpage clearly shows that you should call the `Constants` *constructor*, i.e. `SEASON_DATES = constants.Constants()` (though probably with some arguments).